# Save previos entry per group / id and date in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in python, with the following sorted format:

```
df
Name Date      Value
A    01.01.20  10
A    02.01.20  20
A    03.01.20  15
B    01.01.20  5
B    02.01.20  10
B    03.01.20  5
C    01.01.20  3
C    03.01.20  6
```

So not every Name has every date filled, how can I create a new column with previos date value (if it is missing, just pick the current value) so that it leads to:

```
Name Date      Value  Previos
A    01.01.20  10     10
A    02.01.20  20     10
A    03.01.20  15     20
B    01.01.20  5      5
B    02.01.20  10     5
B    03.01.20  5      10
C    01.01.20  3      3
C    03.01.20  6      6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%y')

df['Previos'] = df.groupby('Name')['Value'].shift().fillna(df['Value'])
print (df)
  Name       Date  Value  Previos
0    A 2020-01-01     10     10.0
1    A 2020-01-02     20     10.0
2    A 2020-01-03     15     20.0
3    B 2020-01-01      5      5.0
4    B 2020-01-02     10      5.0
5    B 2020-01-03      5     10.0
6    C 2020-01-01      3      3.0
7    C 2020-01-03      6      3.0
```

But if need shift by 1 day so in last group are same values like original solution is different - first is created `DatetimeIndex` and for new column is used [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%y')

df = df.set_index('Date')
s = df.groupby('Name')['Value'].shift(freq='D').rename('Previous')
df = df.join(s, on=['Name','Date']).fillna({'Previous': df['Value']})
print (df)
           Name  Value  Previous
Date                            
2020-01-01    A     10      10.0
2020-01-02    A     20      10.0
2020-01-03    A     15      20.0
2020-01-01    B      5       5.0
2020-01-02    B     10       5.0
2020-01-03    B      5      10.0
2020-01-01    C      3       3.0
2020-01-03    C      6       6.0
```